# PhysicsBody Velocity Clamp?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, velocity, chipmunk, clamp

In my app I am simply moving one of the sprites I created in SpriteBuilder like so:

```
[_sprite.physicsBody applyImpulse:ccp(95.0f, 0.0f)];
```

However, if I continuously call this, it will make the sprite go much much faster than I like. Is there a way to use clampf or something to make sure the velocity of the _sprite.physicsBody is in check?

I tried something like this but obviously wont work because it expects float and not CGPoints:

```
_sprite.physicsBody.velocity = clampf(_sprite.physicsBody.velocity, CGPointMake(-100.0f, 0.0f), CGPointMake(0.0f, 100.0f));
```

But is there something similar to this that will achieve what I want while I still use my applyImpulse/applyForce methods to move my physicsBody? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Applying an impulse in that case would be wrong, since you want a constant velocity.

Comment: you need to clamp the point's x and y individually

Comment: @duci9y What would it be then, applyForce?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D That is not possible because the physicsBody's velocity .x and .y are not assignable.

Comment: of course not, you have to assign the velocity to a cgpoint local variable, clamp it, and assign it back to the physicsbody. Cgpoint.x.y are not objc properties, thats why it won't work without the temp variable.

Comment: Ahhh ok I see what you mean @LearnCocos2D. From the other answerer however, what is the proper way to set constant velocity instead of applyImpulse?